# Ajax Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, javascript

Подключил FancyBox Plugin.
При событии click вызывается функция:

```
function GetInfo(type, id){
    $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: {type : type, id : id},
                 cache: false,
                 url: '/admin/index/GetInfo',

                 success: function(data) {
                   $.fancybox(data, {
                      'padding'   : 0,
                      'autoScale'   : false,
                      'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                      'transitionOut' : 'none',
                      'title'     : data.Name,
                      'width'   : 680,
                      'height'    : 495
                   });
                 }
    });

  return false; 
}
```

Но почему-то не появляется всплывающее окно, при этом никаких ошибок js в консоли не наблюдается!

Comment: У fancybox есть же нормальное api для получения контента по ajax. Там через атрибут href работает хорошо.

Comment: Через href не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Попробуй так:
function GetInfo(type, id){
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             data: {'type' : type, 'id' : id},
             cache: false,
             url: '/admin/index/GetInfo',

             success: function(data) {
               $.fancybox(data, {
                  'padding'   : 0,
                  'autoScale'   : false,
                  'transitionIn'  : 'none',
                  'transitionOut' : 'none',
                  'title'     : data.Name,
                  'width'   : 680,
                  'height'    : 495
               });
             }
});

 return false; 
}
```